# My Ubuntu VM needs to connect to a proxy server

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, vmware-esxi

I have created an Ubuntu Server VM on my ESXi server that I access through the VMWare vSphere client. But whenever I try to connect to the internet, it won't work. It is because I am on a company network and I need to connect to a proxy.

However, when I try to connect by doing this:

```
export http_proxy=http://YOUR_PROXY_SERVER:PORT
export ftp_proxy=ftp://YOUR_PROXY_SERVER:PORT
```

It doesn't work. Also, when I try to edit the `apt.conf` it doesn't do what I want.

```
Acquire::protocol::proxy "protocol://user:pass@hostname:port/";
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to make sure your VM can access your company network (check the network card configuration, ip address on the machine, ping gateway, ping your own computer etc.).
Then, try a wget from that machine using your company proxy:

```
# export http_proxy='http://<user>:<pass>@<hostname>:<port>/'
# wget http://www.google.com
```

Make sure you change/update the `http_proxy` with your correct values.
If that works, then you can edit apt.conf accordingly (please make sure you use the right proxy settings).

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work. I checked the pass and username, but I get the message: Proxy authentication required etc. when I try to do the wget

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your system is actually using the proxy server you configured with `tcpdump`. Check with your colleagues if you have the correct settings to access the company proxy. If all else fails, talk to your firewall admins about letting the system access the Internet directly.

Comment: I can connect to the proxy, but the authentication doesn't work